# "Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found" on IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm trying to run an application on IIS at *localhost*, but it is displaying this error message:

```
Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found
```

Here is the **Stack Trace**:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
System.CodeDom.Compiler.RedistVersionInfo.GetCompilerPath(IDictionary`2 provOptions, String compilerExecutable) +8338491
Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +739
Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +170
System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() +12076312
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +301
System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) +12615825
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +50
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +665

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() +80
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +1142
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1193

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618388
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458005
```

I'm using **Windows 8 64-bit**, **Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4** and **IIS 8.5** in a development machine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this specific to the application you're running, or does it happen to the simplest "Hello World" on that machine?

Comment: hello @LeonidTsybert, unfortunately it happens to the simplest "Hello World"... :(

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your OS install.  I recommend reinstalling IIS first, then if that fails the OS.  Csc.exe should exist in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.